# How to creat own custom <?php get_xxxxxx(); ?> function on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to distribute my page contents in various files for a wordpress theme. As I can do with header, sidebar and footer.

Something like

```
<?php get_imageslidercontent(); ?>
```

or anything else.

Comment: Please avoid naming it `get_something()` in case WordPress or a plugin would have the same idea of naming its own function. `nameOfYourThemeOrCompanyOrYourself_something()` would be better ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put this function in the functions.php file that is in your theme root folder and then you can use your function in your theme

Comment: Sorry to say, I don't know much about the coding here. Could you please share me the code? The one that needs go on the function.php

Comment: @Al-Mamun Real I don't understand what you want to do exactly.Please explain.